# Why XDocument can't find my file?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, cocossharp

It's my first question on the forum so don't be too rude please ;)
I used to find answers to my question here but now i'm can't resolve my problem...

I'm currently trying to work with XML files through XDocument in a CocosSharp project.

I'm trying to load an XML file like this:

```
        private string path = "game.xml";

    private void GetXMLData()
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(path);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string s = err.ToString();
        }
    }
```

but it returns me an error

```
"Could not find file \"/game.xml\"."
```

i've tried all the syntax possibilities (~/ / // \ \ ./ .\ ..\ ../) in path
My XML file is set on "Copy if newer" and "embeded ressource" and is store at root.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thx!!

Comment: why not try with full path like `C:\dir\file`

Comment: What's the current directory when you call `XDocument.Load`? You can get it with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: @Flowerking i've just tried with @"D:\_PROJECT_\CocosTag\CocosTag\CocosTag\game.xml it returning me same exception.

Comment: @StevePuder i laready tried but VS2015 can't find Environment.CurrentDirectory. I don't know why

Comment: I'm assuming you're debugging your program (therefor in your `Application\Bin\Debug\` folder) and your `game.xml` file does not exist in the same location you're running from..

Comment: @WinocTessier - You forgot a backslash after `D:`

Comment: @DangerZone but it does exist. i can find the xml file in the Application\Bin\Debug folder
It's just an error during copy/paste it does have the backslash in my program

Comment: @WinocTessier backslashes need to be escaped, or the string needs to be a verbatim '@' string.  e.g. `"D:\\path\\to\\file.xml"` or `@"D:\path\to\file.xml"`.

Comment: @CharlesMager that's was i've done but even with "D:\\\_PROJECT_\\CocosTag\\CocosTag\\CocosTag\\game.xml" it is the same